# Xamarin Forms, Android - Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I'm currently updating a Xamarin Forms App and suddenly experiencing this error on Android:

```
Exception   {Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.alphacoreconsulting.tflmetrosound-Ek3U1cNyzLe9Jayp9enzXQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/c…} Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

It triggers on this line:

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
```

I've researched and I've ensured all packages are the same version:

[image]

Please would anyone be able to offer some help on this?

UPDATE:

I have since updated the proguard.cfg file and added this line:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil
```

After adding this I am now experiencing this error:

```
no static method "Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Landroid/content/Context;)I"
```

Comment: Do you have the linker or proguard enabled?

Comment: The linker is disabled and I'm using the r8 code shrinker not proguard

Comment: You can try to delete the obj folders and bin folders of every platform, then rebuild it.

Comment: If the problem doesn't happen when you have r8 disabled then you need to add an exception using `keep`, `dontwarn`, etc.. R8 is using the same syntax as Proguard. Here is the [Proguard documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows).

Comment: I have added an update to the question. Please see the update. Also @TrevorBalcom your comment resolved my original question so please post as an answer and I will mark it as one. Any help on the next error would really help as there is limited information regarding it out there.

Comment: RE: the `no static method`: I just realized you are referencing a version from 2018. It almost sounds like that old version is calling the now deprecated method [GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil#public-static-int-isgoogleplayservicesavailable-context-context). Can you update the Google Play Services NuGet package? The newer version should use the newer `GoogleApiAvailability` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see this exception at runtime when code has been stripped from the executable usually by the linker or R8/Proguard. You can provide a configuration file to both tools allowing you to keep code the linker or R8/Proguard think you are not using. These tools are not able to properly detect code you use at runtime via reflection for example.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker) for the linker configuration file. Another approach is to use a "LinkerPleaseInclude.cs" file manually referencing the code you do not want to be linked out.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker) for the R8/Proguard configuration file.